# Get POST request data from filter in Enonic

Tags: content-management-system

Are there any ways to use one method for all post requests instead of having controllers for each post request? Can we use HTTP filters in Enonic to support POST requests? They support GET requests by default.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use "[Mappings](https://developer.enonic.com/docs/xp/stable/cms/mappings)" in the Site descriptor to intercept e.g. a path.

```xml
<site>
  <mappings>
    <mapping controller="/site/foobar/api.js" order="10">
      <pattern>/api/v\d+/.*</pattern>
    </mapping>
  </mappings>
</site>
```